# How do I insert data from a dataframe into selected columns in a MySQL table using R

Tags: mysql, r

I have a data frame made up of 3 columns named `INTERNAL_ID`, `NT_CLONOTYPE` and `SAMPLE_ID`.  I need to write a script in R that will transfer this data into the appropriate 3 columns with the exact names in a MySQL table.  However, the table has more than 3 columns, say 5 (`INTERNAL_ID`, `COUNT`, `NT_CLONOTYPE`, `AA_CLONOTYPE`, and `SAMPLE_ID`). The MySQL table already exists and may or may not include preexisting rows of data.

I'm using the dbx and RMariaDB libraries in R. I've been able to connect to the MySQL database with `dbxConnect()`.  When I try to run `dbxUpsert()`

```
-----
conx <- dbxConnect(adapter = "mysql", dbname = "TCR_DB", host = "127.0.0.1", user = "xxxxx", password = "xxxxxxx")

table <- "TCR"
records <- newdf  #dataframe previously created with the update data.

dbxUpsert(conx, table, records, where_cols = c("INTERNAL_ID"))

dbxDisconnect(conx)
```

I expect to obtain an updated mysql table with the new rows, which may or may not have null entries in the columns not contained in the data frame.

```
Ex.
INTERNAL_ID  COUNT  NT_CLONOTYPE  AA_CLONOTYPE SAMPLE_ID
Pxxxxxx.01          CTTGGAACTG                  PMA.01
```

The connection and disconnection all run fin, but instead of the output I obtain the following error:

```
  Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: Field 'COUNT' doesn't have a default value
```

I'm suspecting it's because the number of columns in each file are not the same, but I'm not sure. And if such, how can I get around this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I changed the table entry for "COUNT" to default to NULL.  This allowed for the program to proceed by ignoring "COUNT".